# UIKeyboardTypeURL is showing '.co.uk' instead of '.com'

Tags: ios, localization, uitextfield

I want my textfield keyboard to show a `.com` button. I'm in the UK and it shows a `.co.uk` button instead. How can I change this?

`textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;`

[image: UIKeyboard]

Answer (score 1):

It's not up to you to decide this. It's based on the user location profile.

Comment: I have used apps with a .com button (on the same device)

Comment: Where you simulating any location?

Comment: I'm not using simulator

Comment: There must be an override for this, surely.

Comment: If I change the language of my phone is showing up different domain extension ".com", ".co.uk". You might be able to find the used method and swizzle it.. I've tried to set  "AppleLanguages" to different language in the NSUserDefaults but it didn't work..